# Downloading the android SDK, .exe or .zip?

Tags: android

I was wondering if someone could explain why they give the option for .exe or .zip, and what the pros/cons are

thanks! :D

Comment: The zipped file is smaller by 46221 bytes.

Comment: However, it's not executable!   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are more of a power user, you will probably be more interested in seeing what is in the .zip version. The .exe will simply install and do everything for you, so if you are only interested in getting the SDK installed and ready to use right away, go for that option. On the whole it doesn't really make much difference which version you go for

Comment: Yes, this kind of choice usually boils down to: "if you need to ask, you want the .exe; if you already know, well, you already know"

Comment: If this answered your question you can mark it as answered so he can get rep for it.

Comment: I'm assuming that with the .zip version you can launch the sdk manager and download respective AVDs and whatnot, right?